# How does CardboardView take care of head movement?

Tags: java, android, google-cardboard

Looking through googles [cardboard example](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java) I am wondering, where the head movement transformation takes place, so that the scene or the view is adopted to reflect the head movement.

The interesting methods should be `public void onNewFrame(HeadTransform headTransform)` and `public void onDrawEye(Eye eye)` in the `MainActivity` class.
Here is a snippet:

```
@Override
public void onNewFrame(HeadTransform headTransform) {
   // Build the Model part of the ModelView matrix.
   Matrix.rotateM(modelCube, 0, TIME_DELTA, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

   // Build the camera matrix and apply it to the ModelView.
   Matrix.setLookAtM(camera, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, CAMERA_Z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

   headTransform.getHeadView(headView, 0);

   // Update the 3d audio engine with the most recent head rotation.
   headTransform.getQuaternion(headRotation, 0);
   cardboardAudioEngine.setHeadRotation(
    headRotation[0], headRotation[1], headRotation[2], headRotation[3]);

   checkGLError("onReadyToDraw");
}

@Override
public void onDrawEye(Eye eye) {
   GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   checkGLError("colorParam");

   // Apply the eye transformation to the camera.
   Matrix.multiplyMM(view, 0, eye.getEyeView(), 0, camera, 0);

   // Set the position of the light
   Matrix.multiplyMV(lightPosInEyeSpace, 0, view, 0, LIGHT_POS_IN_WORLD_SPACE, 0);

   // Build the ModelView and ModelViewProjection matrices
   // for calculating cube position and light.
   float[] perspective = eye.getPerspective(Z_NEAR, Z_FAR);
   Matrix.multiplyMM(modelView, 0, view, 0, modelCube, 0);
   Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjection, 0, perspective, 0, modelView, 0);
   drawCube();

   // Set modelView for the floor, so we draw floor in the correct location
   Matrix.multiplyMM(modelView, 0, view, 0, modelFloor, 0);
   Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjection, 0, perspective, 0, modelView, 0);
   drawFloor();
```

}

My first assumption was that the model (or camera) is modified in `onNewFrame()` depending on data from `headTransform`. But this seems not to be the case as there are only two accesses to it. One to identify at which cube we are looking (`headTransform.getHeadView(headView, 0);`) and another for the audio engine.

So my next assumption, and only possibility I see, is that it is handled by the `eye` passed to `onDrawEye()`. But on the other hand after having a short look inside the [disassembly](https://github.com/raasun/cardboard/tree/master/src/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard) I could not find the relation between `headTransform` and `eye` (Which doesn't mean there is no relation, because I haven't invested much time in that).

**So my question:**

Is my assumption right? Does the rendering take the head movement in account by multiplying the `camera` with the eyeView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I spend some more time with browsing the disassembly and it seems as if my assumption was correct.
The private class `RendererHelper` within `CardboardView` implements the following method (it is quite large, so I removed what seems not to be important to me):

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
    // ...

    if (mVRMode)
    {
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mLeftEyeTranslate, 0);
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mRightEyeTranslate, 0);

        Matrix.translateM(mLeftEyeTranslate, 0, halfInterpupillaryDistance, 0.0F, 0.0F);

        Matrix.translateM(mRightEyeTranslate, 0, -halfInterpupillaryDistance, 0.0F, 0.0F);

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mLeftEye.getTransform().getEyeView(), 0, mLeftEyeTranslate, 0, mHeadTransform.getHeadView(), 0);

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mRightEye.getTransform().getEyeView(), 0, mRightEyeTranslate, 0, mHeadTransform.getHeadView(), 0);
    }

    // ...
}
```

The last two matrix multiplications seem to be the place, where the relation between `headTransform` and the `eye` is made.